# Chrome extension icon menu that forces the user to click a radio button, and leverages the choice within the extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is my first question asked at stackoverflow, so if I don't format things well, or violate some rule, please forgive me.  Further, if I haven't provided enough information, just ask for what you need.

I have a fully working Chrome extension.  Currently, the extension shows all data that exists to the user.  I would like to create a popup when the user clicks on the extension icon, and provide them two radio button style choices.  The "All" choice would be defaulted to checked, and the second choice would be "Partial".  Depending on what the user chooses, I would like the extension to show all the data or only partial data.

I have played around with my manifest.json file, and can create the popup with the radio button choices.  What I can't figure out is how to access that choice within my content.js code to determine what the user choose, and subsequently what is shown to the user.  Further, I can't figure out how to save the state of the choice that they make.  In other words, currently, if I click on the icon and choose Partial, the next time I click on it, it just defaults back to the checked state of All (as the code tells it that it is the default).  In addition, ideally this state would be saved even if they close the browser, and come back 2 weeks from now (or whatever amount of time). It would also save the state if they completely rebooted the computer.

Can this be done?  If so, how? Both to saving the state and to accessing the choice they make within my javascript.  Thank you in advance for any assistance provided.

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
**EDIT: New Details**
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

I am very much a noob when it comes to web development.  It took me months to get my Chrome extension to work.  I have spent the past few days researching chrome storage and various examples to try and achieve what I want with no success.  As I am also new to stackoverflow, I am going to TRY and provide some nicely formatted code in the hopes of getting more specific, additional assistance.  Here goes.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Super Extension",
  "description": "My Super Extension Description.",
  "version": "2.7.1",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "icon-32.png"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
      "*://*.url1/*",
      "*://*.url2/*",
      "*://*.url3/*",
      "*://url4/*"    
    ],
    "js": [
      "content.js"
    ],
    "css": [
      "content.css"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_idle"
  }],
  "permissions" : [
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/*",
    "storage"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "32": "icon-32.png",
      "48": "icon-48.png",
      "128": "icon-128.png"
    },
  "default_title": "Click for GCV Options",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      * {box-sizing: border-box;}
      body {width: 160px;}
    </style>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="radio" name="GCVType" checked>Everything
    <input type="radio" name="GCVType">Cards Only
  </body>
</html>
```

I am assuming that within popup.js, I should place the code that can retrieve from storage the (possibly) previously saved state and save the currently chosen selection to storage.

After researching, I found the following example on-line, but simply could not alter it appropriately to get it to work in my situation:

**popup.js**

```
function save_options(){
  var GCV-Key = document.getElementById('GCV-Key').value;

  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    'GCV-Key': GCV-Key
  };
}

function restore_options(){

  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    'GCV-Key': ''
  },
  function(items){
    document.getElementById('GCV-Key').value = items.GCV-Key;
  });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',
    save_options);
```

I know for sure the function(items) has to be changed to reflect what will exist within my content.js file to check for the value.

Here is what SHOULD happen:

1) Basically, the user is going to click on "Everything" or "Cards Only" within the popup (with the initial choice - the first time it is ever run - being "Everything").

2) If the user does not click on anything (or never clicks on the extension icon), I want the value to be "Everything". Further, I want whatever the chosen value is to be stored, so that if they click the extension icon on some future visit, what they previously stored is still there.

3) When content.js runs, I want to examine the value of the saved radio button selection, and I want to change the value of a "const files = ['a', 'b', 'c']" to either "a, b, c" if Everything is the stored value, or change it to "a, b" if Cards Only is the stored value.

In order to accomplish 3) above, I obviously need some kind of listener within content.js so that when the value in storage is changed, the "const files" value can change appropriately.

I simply don't know the exact lines I need to achieve the above.  Nor have I been able to come up with it after much trial/error over the past few days.  So, any and all help would be much appreciated ... credit will be given within the extension.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `chrome.storage` api to save your state to storage then read it when you need it. Add a change listener to your radio input and save the selected state inside the event handler. When the popup is opened read the state from storage and set the radio input's value accordingly.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

Comment: I have appended my original post with more details.  Any further code examples you are will to provide would be appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of problems with your code, for example I don't even think `var GCV-Key` is legal in JS. You should not use hyphens in object keys either, use `GCVKey` instead for example. That is not how `chrome.storage.sync.get` works, check examples. You should read what errors the console says. You probably want to set default values to your settings during installation inside a background script, see how I do it here: https://github.com/gergelyszabo94/csgo-trader-extension/blob/master/extension/src/backgroundScripts/background.js